# Spark org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame: how to calculate avg on the 2nd column

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I wanted to calculate the average on a grouped field similar to the below sql query:

```
select count(*) as total_count
from tbl1
where col2 is NULL;

select col3, count(*)/total_count as avg_count
from tbl1
where col2 is NULL 
group by col3;
```

Please find the Spark statements that I ran through. I already have the `total_count`.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/xxx.db/fff")
val badDF = df.filter("col2 = ' '").withColumn("INVALID_COL_NAME", lit("XXX"))
val badGrp1 = df.groupBy("col3").count() 
val badGrp2 = badGrp1.select(col("col3"),col("count").as("CNT"))
```

Now to find `avg CNT/total_count`, how to proceed?

I tried map and Row, it didn't work.

```
val badGrp3 = badGrp2.map(row => Row(row._1, row._2/20))  ---> for now I am assuming 20 as total_count.
```

Could someone please suggest how to proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Scala but from your code I think that you've considered a `Row` as a Scala `Tuple` in this line of code:

> `val badGrp3 = badGrp2.map(row => Row(row._1, row._2/20))`

To get data from a `Row` in Spark you could use methods of `Row`, just like:

```
// suppose you are getting the 1st and 2nd value of row
// where the 2nd value (count) is a Long type value
row => Row(row.get(0), row.getLong(1)/20)
```

Comment: Thank you Yuan JI.

Comment: your answer helped me and I would vote.

A question: which package Row function belongs to? It gives me error: not found: value Row. I coded as below:

val   badGrp3 = badGrp1.map(row => Row(row.get(0),row.getLong(1)/20)

Also if I have to traverse through all the row of Dataframe, how to do it?
I wanted to call a method for every row of the DF.

Comment: It's `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` you could see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row)

Comment: Thank you. It is working.
I do not see a button to accept the answer. Where is the option?

Comment: Just beside my answer there is a 0 (the vote), you could vote it up, and beneath the vote is the accept button which you could click